How do I solve this "SQL Error (1059): Identifier name 'id_name_host_id_host_name_neighbourhood_group_neighbourhood_latitude...' is too long "
I am importing the data set to my HeidiSQL software, and this is the error message I get
I tried changing the encoding to UFT-8 Unicode. I am able to use load it to RStudio, but very frustrating importing it to MySQL. What I am not doing right, please help.

The linked question is about a long name for a stored procedure, but MySQL has the same length limit for table names, column names, and other identifiers. The answer is the same for all of these identifier types: use a shorter name.
